# Can I remove extra text in the tab name?

Tags: firefox

There's a change to the tab name when I receive a notification on social networking sites.

It'll change from `Website` to `3 Notifications | Website`

I'm curious about ways on Firefox I can prevent that sort of change.

Is it possible to filter out certain words from tab names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title is usually changed by assigning a new value to the `document.title`. You can freeze its value after the page is loaded with this user script:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Freeze title page
// @match       *://*/*
// @run-at      document-idle
// ==/UserScript==

const unsafeDocument = document.wrappedJSObject || document;

let title;
try {
  title = unsafeDocument.head.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerText;
} catch { }
if (!title) {
  title = unsafeDocument.title;
}

Object.defineProperty(unsafeDocument, 'title', {
  get() {
    return title;
  },

  set() { },
});
```

To avoid race condition with other scripts which might change `document.title` the title is read from `<title>` tag.

Note that this solution won't work if the title of the page is set to something like `3 Notifications | Website` with the `<title>` element and not via scripts. In such case I have no idea how to do what you want in a generic way. You can hovewer force a manually-defined title on a per URL basis.

Comment: Great! Where do I add this to apply this to my firefox tabs?

Comment: @Cauder You can use some user script manager like [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) or [Violentmonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/violentmonkey/).

Comment: This doesn't work for me. To repro, I installed this with Greasemonkey and then went to my email provider and sent myself an email. The number in the tab updated.

Comment: @Cauder Sorry, I've only checked it with Violentmonkey. It seems to make it work in Greasemonkey you need to use `document.wrappedJSObject` instead of `document`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Can we change this slightly to say "if the website is X then use the title Y." This script is crashing a website for me

Comment: @Cauder Sure, use [`@match`](https://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40match) key to specify on which domains this script should be run.

Answer (score 2):

You unfortunately cannot prevent tabs from updating the title in any modern browser. The only solution that I've seen, although not ideal, is to use a script to record the initial title of the page and keep the tab updated with that saved value. You can use a greasemonkey script for such a task:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.textContent = "(" + t.toString() + ")()";
document.body.appendChild(script);

var title = document.title;
var updateTitle = function ()
{
      document.title = title;
};
window.setInterval(updateTitle, 0);
```

Comment: @Cauder Yes, you just need the [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) extension.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. To repro, I installed this with Greasemonkey and then went to my email provider and sent myself an email. The number in the tab updated.

Comment: Can we change this slightly to say "if the website is X then use the title Y." This script is crashing a website for me